# Is there a more elegant way of writing this in Python - Splitting out a dictionary value into a list of Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to find a more simpler way of splitting a dictionary string value into a dictionary list:

```
d = [{"name": "Fruit list 1", "fruits": "apple| pear", "cost": "23.56"}, {"name": "Fruit list 2", "fruits": "pineapple| orange| grape", "cost": "10.00"}, {"name": "Fruit list 3", "fruits": "apple| strawberry", "cost": "13.56"}]
```

I want to split out the fruits key into a list of dictionaries like:

```
[{"name": "Fruit list 1", "fruits": [{"value": "apple"}, {"value": "pear"}], "cost": "23.56"}, {"name": "Fruit list 2", "fruits": [{"value": "pineapple"}, {"value": "orange"}, {"value": "grape"}], "cost": "10.00"}, {"name": "Fruit list 3", "fruits": [{"value": "apple"}, {"value": "strawberry"}], "cost": "13.56"}]
```

I have written this as:

```
    import ast

    for line in d:
        f = ""
        for fruit in line["fruits"].split("|"):
            if f == "":
                f = "{\"value\": \"" + fruit.strip() + "\"}"
            else:
                f = f + ", {\"value\": \"" + fruit.strip() + "\"}"
        line["fruits"] = [ast.literal_eval(f)]
```

Just looking for a more elegant solution, thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: This sort of post is better sent to CR (code-review) not SO...

Comment: Better in CR, yes -- but since it's specific Python programming tricks, it's a style of question usually acceptable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you're trying to modify the original list of dicts?

```
    for line in d:
        f = []
        for fruit in line["fruits"].split("|"):
            f.append( {'value': fruit} )
        line["fruits"] = f
```

or

```
    for line in d:
        line['fruits'] = [ {'value': fruit} for fruit in line["fruits"].split("|") ]
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, I was so close I had the curly brace at the end rather than before the for. Thank you for taking the time to help me.